# Removing a malware that sets up as a system driver

Tags: windows-vista, boot, malware, safe-mode

I recently tried to fix up my mother's computer which has some serious malwares.

One of them apparently registered itself as system driver (`tjbijkoq.sys` if that can help) and after running a malware suppression tool, the computer won't boot anymore, complaining about a **"critical driver that is missing"**.

I think deleting the matching entry in the registry would just solve the problem, but obviously I can't boot up the computer (even in safe mode) to fix it.

Do you guys have any experience with such an issue and how to solve this ?

Thank you very much.

*The operating system is Windows Vista 32 bits Professional*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably suggest a reinstall, or if you don't want to nuke it from orbit- , [a repair install](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial148.html). You will need a working vista cd to do the latter, and either a OEM restore disk, or vista cd for the former.

Comment: And don't forget to unplug it from any kind of network until you could install a firewall and the most important security fixes!